# Mapping null string with ConvertUsing(Func<TSource, TDestination, TDestination> mappingFunction)

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to map strings to enums using `.ConvertUsing(Func<TSource, TDestination, TDestination> mappingFunction)`. The problem I'm seeing is that when calling `mapper.Map<InternalDeliveryType>(string source)`, `mappingFunction` isn't executed when `source` is `null`. The result is default value for the enum.

Full gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/CNBoland/1a42e46f555cbcb15e114222ce27a2ea).

Here's a snippet for illustration:

```
var mapperCfg = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<string, InternalDeliveryType>()
    .ConvertUsing((s, d) =>
    {
        return s switch
        {
            null => InternalDeliveryType.Electronic,
            ExternalDeliveryType.Electronic => InternalDeliveryType.Electronic,
            ExternalDeliveryType.Paper => InternalDeliveryType.Paper,

            _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Mapping '{s}' to {nameof(InternalDeliveryType)}.")
        };
    });
});

var mapper = mapperCfg.CreateMapper();

string? externalDeliveryType = null; // Inbound from external API.
var internalDeliveryType = mapper.Map<InternalDeliveryType>(externalDeliveryType);
Debug.Assert(internalDeliveryType == InternalDeliveryType.Electronic);
```

Comment: `mapper.Map<string, InternalDeliveryType>(externalDeliveryType);`

Comment: But `string` to `enum` is built-in, so maybe you don't need the converter?